# How to convert times (like 34:00 ) into slider Maximum value on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, timestamp, nsdate, uislider

I am creating an app that downloads podcasts from a web service and displays them in a tableView. When a podcast is touched, the individual podcast is loaded.

The podcast:duration comes as "1:20:43" time. Some of them are shorter ("45:10") and some are longer ("1:23:11")

I would like the user to be able to seek through the podcast using a slider. The maximumValue of the slider should be the podcast:duration of the individual podcast.

I tried saving the podcast:duration as a string, then using dateFromString to get the date, and setting that to the maximumValue of the slider.  The problem is the maximumValue of the slider takes a double.

What class should I make the podcast:duration and how do I convert it into the maximumValue of the slider?  What is the right way to deal with times in iOS?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the duration into seconds then the slider value sets the percentage?